# How to capture boostrap CSS change in HtmlUnit?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, htmlunit

"show" class is added into modal when modal is trigger to be displayed by button, but unfortunately it is unable to be captured by XPath, showing as null.

Java

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:7001/JavaWebExample/modal.html");
    
    HtmlButton showModalBtn = (HtmlButton) page.getFirstByXPath("//button[@id='showModalBtn' and contains(@class, 'btn')]");
    page = showModalBtn.click();
    logger.debug("showModalBtn: {}", showModalBtn);
    
    HtmlDivision exampleModal = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='exampleModal' and contains(@class, 'show')]");
    logger.debug("exampleModal: {}", exampleModal);
}
```

HTML

```
<button
        id="showModalBtn"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Launch demo modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
<div
    class="modal fade"
    id="exampleModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                    id="modalCloseBtn"
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Log

> 2023-03-28 16:28:59 SGT [1] [DEBUG] (ModalTest.java:46) c.e.ModalTest
> contentTest - showModalBtn: HtmlButton[] 2023-03-28 16:28:59 SGT [1] [DEBUG]
> (ModalTest.java:49) c.e.ModalTest contentTest - exampleModal: null

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues and please provide a sample page and maybe some minimal sample code to give me a chance to reproduce this.

Comment: He Error 404 - i really like to work on this; any chance to open an issue?